# Remove characters from string regex java

Tags: java, regex

Hello guys I'm starting to learn regex and I want to replace some characters from string.

this is my test case:

**Example string:**

```
+52 924 340 2304
```

**Expected output:**

```
09243402304
```

This is what I've tried:

```
String number = cursor.getString(col_number).replace("\\d{2}", "");
```

But I can't seem to get my expected output. Any help? I would gladly appreciate your help. Thanks.

**Update:**

Also, I want to remove all whitespace characters from the string and I forgot to add if the string has other characters like (,),-

Comment: Don't use regex for this, you can simply cut the number using `substring`.

Answer (score 1):

Your method:

```
.replace("\\d{2}", "");
```

will fail to work because in Java `String#replace` **doesn't take a regex**. Try `String#replaceAll` OR `String#replaceFirst`

You can use:

```
String number = cursor.getString(col_number).replace(" ", "").replaceFirst("\\+\\d{2}", "0");
```

Comment: I'm only getting 0. not my expected result.

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
.replaceAll("^[^\\s]+|\\s", "")
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/uY9xB2/1

Comment: thanks it works! But I have to change to: replaceAll("^[^\\s]+|\\s", "")

Comment: instead of negated character class, you could use `^\\S+`

Answer (score 1):

```
String number = cursor.getString(col_number).replaceAll("^\\+\\d{2}", "0").replaceAll("[^\\d]", "")
```

Comment: @Cedy Lee, I suppose you want to remove everything that's not a digit? There's a way for that, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not split the `String` at the whitespaces. Then you replace the first entry with a `0`, and concatenate the array parts to one `String` again. Done.

Answer (score 0):

@anibhava already mentioned your problem, I want to suggest another solution, you can simply remove the white spaces and cut the string using [`String#substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)):

```
number.replaceAll("\\s+", "").substring(3); //you might want to add the 0 using + operator
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^\+\d{2}[^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*(\d+)$
```

You can use this and then replace with

```
 0$1$2$3
```

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iX5xR2/12

This will work for all cases